# How to Use ESNext with NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am using NestJS. I have updated the generated `tsconfig.json` to include:

```json
"lib": ["ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext"
```

It also includes: `"include": ["src/**/*"]`

No TS errors, but upon running, I get `Cannot find module` errors in the output.

Actually,this issue exists simply from changing the `tsconfig.json` to use `ESNext`. So, somehow Nest is not compatible with `ESNext`?

And, yes, I have `"type": "module"` in `package.json` also.

For completeness, kindly see here the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change it to `ES2022` for everything instead of `ESNext`? `ESNext` just transpiles ES6 (ES2015) code to code that will work today. Also, looking into NestJS, it looks like it is used for JavaScript mainly, not with TypeScript.

Comment: Despite the name, it does favor TS primarily. Running `nest new` defaults to using TS. It is compatible with both. https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps I will try `"ES2022"` bit later, but don't suspect that that will make a difference. Will post back if it does. Tx.